# powershell: Trying to figure out 5 multiline textbox line by line content array into 2 files, foreach isn't the correct approach (example below)

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell GUI with 5 multiline textboxes. I'm trying to figure how to get the content of each line and update files as needed (up to 100s of files eventually) with each line.

Here's an example of the code:

> textbox1.lines test values: test0001 test0002 test0003
>
> textbox2.lines test values: a b c
>
> textbox3.lines test values: app web db
>
> textbox4.lines test values: 1 2 3
>
> textbox5.lines test values: small medium large

```
    $is = $textbox1.Lines

    $azs = $textbox2.Lines

    $functions=$textbox3.Lines

    $rgs=$textbox4.Lines

    $instancetypes=$textbox5.Lines

    foreach ($i in $is)
        {

        foreach ($a in $azs)
        {
            foreach ($function in $functions)
            {
                foreach ($rg in $rgs)
                {
                    foreach ($instancetype in $instancetypes)
                    {
        get-content "path\tofile\params_ans_dvw$i.yml" | 
            foreach-object { 
                $_ -replace "ans-server-name", "dvw$i" 
            } | 
            set-content "path\tofile\params_ans_dvw$i.yml" 

        get-content "path\tofile\params_ans_dvw$i.yml" | 
            foreach-object { 
                $_ -replace "ans-server-name", "dvw$i" 
            } | 
            set-content "path\tofile\params_ans_dvw$i.yml"

        get-content "path\tofile\params_ans_dvw$i.yml" | 
            foreach-object { 
                $_ -replace "ans-server-name", "dvw$i" 
            } | 
            set-content "path\tofile\params_ans_dvw$i.yml"
        ###### This part works for all 3 variable values from textbox1

        ##### The remaining variables fail to add items line by line, it grabs the last (3rd) value for all entries (?)
        Get-Content "path\tofile\params_dvw$i.json" | 
            foreach-object { 
                $_ -replace "availability-zone", "us-east-1$a" 
            } | 
            Set-Content "path\tofile\params_DVW$i.json"

        Get-Content "path\tofile\params_dvw$i.json" | 
            foreach-object { 
                $_ -replace "availability-zone", "us-east-1$a" 
            } | 
            Set-Content "path\tofile\params_DVW$i.json"

        Get-Content "path\tofile\params_dvw$i.json" | 
            foreach-object {
                $_ -replace "availability-zone", "us-east-1$a" 
            } | 
            Set-Content "path\tofile\params_DVW$i.json"
                 }
                }
            }


    }
```

> Is it possible that I could add all 5 variable groups into an array and update the file with each line of the 5 textboxes?
>   I'm fairly new to powershell
>
> I believe I have the creation of the array correct:

```
$appname="TestArray"
$appportid="A9SD7FASDFASDF987AS90DF87"

$is= ("server1","server2","server3")
$azs= ("a", "b", "c")
$functions= ("web","app","db")
$rgs= (1,2,3)
$instancetypes= ("small", "medium", "large")

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$ArrayList = ($is +=$azs += $functions +=$rgs +=$instancetypes)

$ArrayList

rm C:\temp\array\*.json
rm C:\temp\array\*.yml

foreach ($i in $is)
    {


        Copy-Item "C:\temp\params_ans_test.yml" "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml"
        Copy-Item "C:\temp\params_test.json" "c:\temp\array\params_dvw$i.json"


        (get-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml") | foreach-object { $_ -replace "ans-server-name", "dvw$i" } | set-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml"
        (get-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml") | foreach-object { $_ -replace "ans-environment", "dev" } | set-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml"
        (get-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml") | foreach-object { $_ -replace "ans-rebootgroup", "$rg" } | set-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml"
        (get-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml") | foreach-object { $_ -replace "ans-dynatrace-hostgroup", "$($appname)_Dev" } | set-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml"
        (get-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml") | foreach-object { $_ -replace "app-port-id", "$appportid" } | set-content "c:\temp\array\params_ans_dvw$i.yml"
        (Get-Content "c:\temp\array\params_dvw$i.json") | foreach-object { $_ -replace "server-instance-type", "$instancetype" } | Set-Content "c:\temp\array\params_dvw$i.json"
        (Get-Content "c:\temp\array\params_dvw$i.json") | foreach-object { $_ -replace "server-function", "$function" } | Set-Content "c:\temp\array\params_dvw$i.json"
        (Get-Content "c:\temp\array\params_dvw$i.json") | foreach-object { $_ -replace "availability-zone", "us-east-1$az" } | Set-Content "c:\temp\array\params_dvw$i.json"

    }
```

> The question is: How do I add the remaining content of the array to these files

Comment: PLEASE, fix your code formatting. the instructions are linked on the page that you used to create your question.

Comment: Fixed, hopefully

Comment: Hi haffapappa--your code seems wrong relative to your description.  You can concatenate arrays in PowerShell by either adding the arrays together with the '+' operator or using the '+=' operator to concatenate them together.  $test = @(1, 2) + @(3, 4) + @(5, 6)

Comment: @haffapappa - much better ... thank you! [*grin*]

Comment: hi thepip3r, you're right. I was trying foreach to send line by line vaiables to 2 files with content from the 5 different multiline textboxes (hence that script currently).
I'm not familiar with arrays so I put the title that I'm trying to reach, but also giving a glance of my current mayhem ;).

I just really need help with the array concept, I've googled my eyeballs out. But mostly found definitions and concepts, not working examples.

i can fix the title